Firebase Admin SDK: Authentication failed using Compute Engine authentication due to unavailable metadata server
When I try to send a push notification with firebase admin sdk from my own Django server.  I get this error: Authentication failed using Compute Engine authentication due to unavailable metadata server.

I created a Google service account from my firebase console.
Generated a new private key.
Added the google.json file in my project and set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with the file path.

Basically, I followed the steps indicated in "Initialize the SDK in non-Google environments" part of the official firebase documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk_in_non-google_environments
When sending push notification with Firebase Admin SDK from my local Django server  I successfully receive push notification on my mobile device. But it does not work from my remote server (AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance).

Python version: 3.10.12
Django version: 5.0.4

Do you have any idea what could be the cause ?

Your approach should work but it appears that it's reaching step #3 in the Search Order suggesting that it isn't actually finding the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or its value correctly. Can you validate this? Perhaps add a logging line in your Django server that outputs the value of this environment variable?

Since you're running on AWS, once you solve this problem, a more secure approach may be to use Workload Identity Federation

@DazWilkin Thank you, you helped me understand that the variable is actually not set.  I noticed that when I print the value of the environment variable, it is None. However when I echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in the terminal or print the variable in a Python shell it outputs the value correctly. The workaround that I found is set the value  of the variable in Django settings with os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]. But it is not good practice because I hard coded the file path. Now I will figure out the proper way to set the environment variable.

Yes, you want to resolve why the environment is not passing through to the Django server. Is the server running in a container perhaps? Then you'd need to mount the key and reference it in the container's environment. The benefit of Application Default Credentials is that it permits abstracting credentials from your code so please don't hardcode the value. Also, investigate Workload Identity Federation.
